# ios - is it possible to send message to device with delivery confirmation

Tags: ios, background, push-notification, enterprise

A very simple task that took me 30 minutes to implement on an android.

A web server sends a message to device. **Without user interaction** a receipt is sent back. User understands that this is a desired  behavior. When user opens the app he/she can send additional acknowledgement.

My understanding is that as long as I am not using location service I cannot run app in background continuously (or periodically). Push notifications will require user interaction, otherwise it's just a badge and a message.

This seems like a trivial problem but makes my head hurt and want me to give up.
Is Enterprise subscription the only way for me to get the app to our company users?

Comment: You are correct. iOS does not support this scenario. there is no way for you app to receive data and respond without user interaction when it is not already running.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to ask user permission to send PUSH notifications. Once the user agrees for you to send PUSH notifications to his device, you need to get the device ID and store it in your servers. This is the FIRST phase of PUSH-NOTIFICATION

In the next phase (SECOND phase), lets say you want to notify the user about something, what you do is get all deviceIDs for that user (he might have registered more than 1 iOS device) and send some X message to his device(s) leveraging apple's PUSH infrastructure. You need to pass the deviceID's to Apple (along with a bunch of other stuff) as this is how it identifies which device gets this X message.

Also initially while registering for PUSH, you need to write a little code to configure how your PUSH notification will look like. Would it have SOUND, BADGE, MESSAGE etc.

For all this to happen you as a app developer do not need to concern whether you app is ACTIVE or not. iOS takes care of it. After the initial PUSH registration the user too is not involved. You dont need to run your app in the background nor do you need to register for continuous location updates.

Have I understood your question correctly?

Comment: Thank you for reply, but I think you misunderstood. The whole point of such app would be sending a receipt to server upon receiving notification - whether push or some other form - without user attention.